# Remove commas in Data Explorer query for CSV export

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am working on linguistic analyses on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I am running a query in the Data Explorer that grabs all the user information. The query is the following:

```
select * from Users;
```

The query is fine but some fields include commas, which messes up the CSV when I try to import it into Excel. How would you modify the query so that commas could be replaced by something else such as a space?

Comment: @CloseVoter : Where would a question about the Data Explorer query go if not here ?

Comment: Stack Overflow @return, this is a SQL question and I'm the obvious close voter as I say it in my answer :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards didn't read that far haha thanks :P

Comment: The problem is likely stray *quotation* marks, by the way, as the values are qualified by quotes in the generated CSV.

Comment: *sigh*, breaking my answer @Tim... can't you fix that in the export? (once some code gets pushed there :-)

Comment: I think that Excel accepts `""` as an escape for an embedded double-quote, so it might be sensible if Data Explorer handled that itself (or allowed for it to be configurable).

Comment: It does @Tim, yes. <generic whine about Microsoft and standards/>

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Huh, Data Explorer actually does do this already, so I'm not sure what happened in the OP's case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`REPLACE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
select id, replace(<comma field>, ',', ' ') as some_column
  from users
```

P.S. This is really off-topic for MSO.

If, as Tim says, it's stray quotation marks then you need to replace them with 2 as per RFC 4180

```
select id, replace(<comma field>, '"','""') as some_column
  from users
```

Comment: Put two replaces in there @user1029296 `replace(replace(<blah>,'a', 'b'), 'g', 'h')` The point isn't to replace the quotation marks though, it's to make your extract to conform to the RFC so that they _remain_ in your data.